# Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I am try to show data in custom list, but when i am trying to showing data the the inflate Exception occur , i search a lot but not found the solution.

log cat..

```
Process: com.example.directory, PID: 19288
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:121)
        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

below is the main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/jsonDataListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the main_single_row.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sw_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@string/paddingLeft"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sw_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@string/paddingLeft"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sw_location"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@string/paddingLeft"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sw_address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@string/paddingLeft"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sw_phone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@string/paddingLeft"
    android:text="" />
```

here is the sample of code where i load the data in the custom xml.

```
        ListView jsons_dta = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.jsonDataListView);
        String[] data = { id, name, address, location, phNo };
        int[] id = { R.id.sw_id, R.id.sw_name,
                R.id.sw_address,R.id.sw_location, R.id.sw_phone };

        ListAdapter adpter = new SimpleAdapter(json_data.this, sw_list,
                R.layout.single_item_json_data, data, id);
        jsons_dta.setAdapter(adpter);
```

Comment: post your all code....logcat error pointing to some where else...

Comment: Post your complete LogCat

Answer (score 0):

change this get int value from dimen not from strings.

```
android:paddingLeft="@string/value"
to 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/xyz"
```